# What function did the ribbed portions of the Saturn V exterior serve?

Tags: rockets, saturn-v

I would like to know what function did the ribbed portions on Saturn V exterior serve, such as the the intertank section and forward skirt on Stage 1. Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to Saturn V? If that's the case, it would be good to edit both the title and the body. It would also be good to expand the body so that it can be understood without re-reading the title: i.e. title: What function did the ribbed portions on Saturn V exterior serve?
Body: I would like to know what function did the ribbed portions on Saturn V exterior serve, such as the the intertank section and forward skirt on Stage 1. Thank you!

Comment: PS: Welcome to Space Exploration Beta!

Answer (score 7):

That's called [corrugated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrugated_galvanised_iron) sheet metal. The function of the corrugations is to make the material stiffer in the direction of the corrugations.

Although instead of corrugations, stringers were often used to serve the same purpose, such as on the [Saturn V](https://historicspacecraft.com/Rockets_Saturn_5.html):

[image]

This solution is easier to fabricate than pressing corrugations into a conical sheet of metal.

They were used on those sections where the skin isn't pressurized: the tanks are stiff enough not to need stringers, the non-tank sections (interstage, intertank sections) did need them.

Comment: I love this building!

Comment: These are also used by slower, smaller craft.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longeron